# substring or slice without the wanted results in Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, opera, slice

```
var keuzekaart = unescape(document.cookie);
var string = (keuzekaart.slice(0,6));
```

This gives the wanted results in Safari and IE. 
In FF the result is: 'keuzek'.
In Opera and Chrome the console.log stays empty. I don't know if thats because of the slice function or because console.log doesn't work properly in those browsers.

Comment: Can you show us how you used `console.log` and what results it gave you? `console.log` does work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what exactly the code should do? If you are trying to modify or read cookies then you should take a look at a javascript library which handles this for you, like:

- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
- https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies

Comment: In this case the first 6 characters should be sliced off (fi: 26.jpg). I have also tried the 'substring' function, with the same result.

Comment: I dont recommend accessing cookie data by looking at a position within a string that may vary between http requests. Something that may work now can fail later if code is modified to add more cookies or cookies are being placed in a different order. Please take a look at the recommended libraries in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code and included the jquerie-cookie. Again Safari is doing well and FF, Opera and Chrome are acting the same way. So there must be a fault in the slice operation. The variable 'keuzekaart'is undefined, somehow.` var keuzekaart = $.cookie('the_cookie');
    var string = (keuzekaart.slice(0,6));`